# Optimizing Large Data Transfer from FastAPI ecs service to ECS Task Triggered by EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs, aws-event-bridge

Main ECS Service:

This FastAPI service handles incoming requests with binary data.

Upon receiving the request, this service will process the data

ECS Tasks:
The ECS tasks is designed to run when triggered by EventBridge events.

Processing data:

The extract_information function within the ECS task will perform the actual processing of the data.

Given that the main service is based on FastAPI and the ECS task is triggered by EventBridge, what would be the most efficient and scalable approach to send large data (approximately 3GB or more) from the main service to the ECS task? Are there specific considerations or optimizations within FastAPI and EventBridge that can be leveraged for this purpose?

we thought of using sqs but the limit is 256kib per message... and it offers to send nearly 2gb data using extended client library in java (i use python):-https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-s3-messages.html

and i cannot use lambda function so please do not include it in the solution thank you